# Kusto (Azure Data Explorer): How to filter results by a given key-value filters dictionary

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto Function that runs a query, and I want to add an input parameter that will be used to filter the data inside the Function.

Lets say the Function's body is the below, on a Table that has `Dimensions` column with `JSON (string)` value

```
Table
| summarize count()
```

and I want to add a parameter 'filterDictionary', and keep the results that comply with the filter paramters, **in pseudo code**:

```
Table
for each key-value in the 'filterDictionary', filter with:
      where Dimensions[key_i] == value_i
| summarize count()
```

**Is it possible? What is the best way to do it?**

Let's say an example of 'filterDictionary' can be:

```
{
  "DataCenter": "CUS",
  "Result": "Failure"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a shortcut for `| summarize count()` you can simply use `| count`

Answer (score 1):

Using [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator), per `t` record, we pass over `filterDictionary` keys and count the number of mismatches between `filterDictionary[k]` and `t[k]`.
We filter out only 0 mismatches.

```
.create-or-alter function f(filterDictionary:dynamic)
{
    // Generate data sample. Not part of the solution.
    let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend dummy1 = toint(rand(100)), dummy2 = toint(rand(100)), Dimensions = dynamic_to_json(pack_dictionary("Result", tostring(dynamic(["Failure", "Success"])[toint(rand(2))]), "ZDummy", toint(rand(100)), "DataCenter", tostring(dynamic(["AUS", "BUS", "CUS", "DUS", "EUS"])[toint(rand(5))]), "MDummy2", toint(rand(100)))));
    // Solution starts here.
    t
    | extend _Dimensions = todynamic(Dimensions)
    | mv-apply _k = bag_keys(filterDictionary) to typeof(string) on 
      (
          summarize _count_diff = countif(tostring(filterDictionary[_k]) != tostring(_Dimensions[_k])), _max = arg_max(1, *) 
        | where _count_diff == 0
      )
    | project-away _*
}
```

---

```
f(dynamic({"DataCenter": "CUS", "Result": "Failure"}))
```

| i | dummy1 | dummy2 | Dimensions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 29 | 79 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":88,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":29} |
| 23 | 52 | 84 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":38,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":2} |
| 26 | 60 | 4 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":12,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":89} |
| 32 | 30 | 77 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":79,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":4} |
| 33 | 32 | 64 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":46,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":69} |
| 44 | 31 | 77 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":0,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":98} |
| 47 | 55 | 55 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":13,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":25} |
| 67 | 43 | 50 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":7,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":21} |
| 86 | 45 | 66 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":63,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":55} |

Answer (score 0):

By using [bag_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bagkeysfunction) & [bag_remove_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-remove-keys-function) we create a subset of `Dimensions` that has the same keys as `filterDictionary`.
Using [dynamic_to_json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dynamic-to-json-function), we change them both to their canonical string representation and then compare them.

```
.create-or-alter function f(filterDictionary:dynamic)
{
    // Generate data sample. Not part of the solution.
    let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend dummy1 = toint(rand(100)), dummy2 = toint(rand(100)), Dimensions = dynamic_to_json(pack_dictionary("Result", tostring(dynamic(["Failure", "Success"])[toint(rand(2))]), "ZDummy", toint(rand(100)), "DataCenter", tostring(dynamic(["AUS", "BUS", "CUS", "DUS", "EUS"])[toint(rand(5))]), "MDummy2", toint(rand(100)))));
    // Solution starts here.
    t
    | extend _Dimensions = todynamic(Dimensions)
    | where dynamic_to_json(bag_remove_keys(_Dimensions, bag_keys(bag_remove_keys(_Dimensions, bag_keys(filterDictionary))))) == dynamic_to_json(filterDictionary)
    | project-away _Dimensions
}
```

---

```
f(dynamic({"DataCenter": "CUS", "Result": "Failure"}))
```

| i | dummy1 | dummy2 | Dimensions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 16 | 22 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":19,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":90} |
| 6 | 33 | 29 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":60,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":65} |
| 7 | 92 | 90 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":38,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":6} |
| 12 | 36 | 71 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":57,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":91} |
| 46 | 95 | 0 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":67,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":0} |
| 62 | 97 | 4 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":35,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":1} |
| 80 | 71 | 57 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":7,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":92} |
| 88 | 4 | 33 | {"DataCenter":"CUS","MDummy2":41,"Result":"Failure","ZDummy":58} |

Comment: thanks, applying it on my data doesn't work, from a quick look i think you rely on the fact the both `Dimensions` JSONs have the same properties right?
The `Dimensions` property of the actual table can contain more keys that the ones I want to filter with.
Any idea? thanks!

Comment: No, you can see in my example that my code was tested on Dimension with additional columns.

Comment: Have you figured out what didn't work when executed on your data?